# Prevent LinkedResource image getting added as attachment

Tags: asp.net, email, embedded-resource

On a page that sends emails using System.Net.Mail I have this to embed an image into a html formatted email.

```
string logoPath = "W:\\WebSites\\logo.jpg";
            LinkedResource imagelink = new LinkedResource(logoPath, "image/jpg");
            imagelink.ContentId = "imageId";
            imagelink.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.Base64;
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(MessageHeader + Message.ToString() + MessageFooter, null, "text/html");
            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(imagelink);
```

In the code that creates the email, the image is embedded like this.

```
MessageHeader += "<img alt=\"Company Logo\" hspace=0 src=\"cid:imageId\" align=baseline border=0>";
```

This all works okay. The logo appears in the html formatted email where it should be. But, when users receive the email there is also an attached image - in Outlook you see an attachment always called ATT00001 - which, if you download, is the logo image.

How can I prevent the logo getting added as an attachment as well as being embedded? It looks unprofessional to have the logo in the message but also attached waiting to be downloaded. Users complain they think there is an attachment - but in fact it is just the logo.

Comment: I get that all the time. I always thought it was because I set a setting to not show images by default, but they have to be included somehow. Not sure though. You're getting both, image and att?

Comment: Yes I get both. The image gets embedded in my html email correctly but it also shows up as an attachment when viewed in an email client. I  just tried changing the image from a jpg to a png and it doesn't get attached. Isn't technology great!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? My code used to work correctly, but for some reason after a while it started to do the same thing that you described.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution for this question. When you add the LinkedResource object, you have to define the correct MIME type, and if you do so, the email client won't offer the embedded images as attachments.

Here is a sample code grabbed from my scenario (vb.net code):

```
    'Your email
    Dim _htmlSource As New StringBuilder("<html> ... YOUR HTML EMAIL ... </html>")
    Dim _linkedResources As New List(Of LinkedResource)
    Dim _href As String = "http://your.image.url/image.png"


    'Adding images
    Dim _imageStream As MemoryStream
    Dim _mimeType As String
    Using _wc = New WebClient
        _imageStream = New MemoryStream(_wc.DownloadData(_href))
        _mimeType = _wc.ResponseHeaders("content-type")
    End Using
    Dim _contentId As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString

    _htmlSource.Replace(_href, "cid:" & _contentId)
    _linkedResources.Add(New LinkedResource(_imageStream, New ContentType(_mimeType)) With {.ContentId = _contentId})



    'Compile mail message
    Dim mail As New MailMessage
    mail.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim _htmlView As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(_htmlSource.ToString(), Nothing, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html)
    _htmlView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.EightBit
    _linkedResources.ForEach(Sub(lr) _htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(lr))
```